# When Rating Deviation from Mean Agreement in using detecting fake profile is accepted?

Tags: python, recommendation-engine

First I create attacking file (based on the ua.base file in https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens), its structure will look like this:

- From user has id from **1 to 893**, its data is **original**.
- From user has id from **893 to 943** (50 users), i change it into **attack profile** (its modal is Love/Hate attack modal), its rating for **item id 19 is 1** (min value) and **50 items** are chosen **randomly** has **5** in rating value (max value), **the last part is empty**.

I have written the function to calculate RDMA for each profile.

I also have read some document (https://dslab.epfl.ch/people/zamfir/widm2005.pdf, or http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.329.4891&rep=rep1&type=pdf), it said that RDMA is used for detecting fake profile.

But the problem is i don't know when one RDMA is acceptable, one RDMA is not. I just don't know clearly its bound to determine for coding.

I am new to this. Sorry for any un-convinient if i have made.

Comment: I'm not familiar with RDMA, but I am guessing it is going to require some tuning/training for your application.